# Cakephp, don't use a database table

Tags: database, cakephp, model

I don't a controllers model to use a database table.

I have a pages controller and model but it is saying "pages table not found". How do I tell the model not to use a the database at all?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`useTable`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1059/useTable) property of the model to `false`.

Comment: You can also use var $uses = null on the controller.